# Split Records based on Time Duration

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've got this table which contains time spent in various states for the agents in our Call Center.
Here is an example of one of the records:

```
AgentName, AgentState, BeginTransitionTime, EndTransitionTime, BeginHour,   EndHour

Breana Rascon(994840), Work Time, 3/14/16 7:56:19 AM, 3/14/16 11:02:51 AM, 7,   11
```

I'd like the above  record to end up split into 5 records, as so:

```
Breana Rascon(994840), Work Time, 3/14/16 7:56:19 AM, 3/14/2016 7:59:59 AM, 7,  7

Breana Rascon(994840), Work Time, 3/14/16 8:00:00 AM, 3/14/2016 8:59:59 AM, 8,  8

Breana Rascon(994840), Work Time, 3/14/16 9:00:00 AM, 3/14/2016 9:59:59 AM, 9,  9

Breana Rascon(994840), Work Time, 3/14/16 10:00:00 AM, 3/14/2016 10:59:59 AM,   10, 10

Breana Rascon(994840), Work Time, 3/14/16 11:00:00 AM, 3/14/16 11:02:51 AM, 11, 11
```

I started out used a cursor, which worked just fine when the record was split over 2 hours, but more than that and the code started getting out of hand.  Any help at all would be highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: what is the criteria for splitting into 5 ?,is this same for all?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a numbers table, it's a simple join and some conversions.  Otherwise you'll need a CTE or some other windowing function.

**numberz table**

```
DECLARE @UpperLimit INT = 1000000;

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.numberz','U') IS NULL 
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE dbo.numberz (numVal INT);

    WITH n(rn) AS
    (
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
      FROM sys.all_columns AS s1
      CROSS JOIN sys.all_columns AS s2
    )
    INSERT dbo.numberz
    SELECT [numVAl] = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT rn
    FROM n
    WHERE rn <= @UpperLimit;

    CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX uix_numVal ON dbo.numberz([numVAl]);
END
```

**Table Creation**

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_agentTime
(
      AgentName           NVARCHAR(255)
    , AgentState          NVARCHAR(255)
    , BeginTransitionTime DATETIME
    , EndTransitionTime   DATETIME
    , BeginHour           INT
    , EndHour             INT
)

INSERT tbl_agentTime
VALUES ('BREANA RASCON(994840)', 'WORK TIME', '2016-03-14 7:56:19', '2016-03-14 11:02:51', 7, 11)
```

**Record Split**

```
select 
      AgentName
    , AgentState
    , BeginTransitionTime = CASE WHEN numVal = BeginHour then BeginTransitionTime else cast(cast(BeginTransitionTime as date) as nvarchar(10)) +' '+cast(numVal as nvarchar(2))+':00:00' end 
    , EndTransitionTime   = CASE WHEN numVal = EndHour   then EndTransitionTime   else cast(cast(ENDTRANSITIONTIME   as date) as nvarchar(10)) +' '+cast(numVal as nvarchar(2))+':59:59' end 
    , BeginHour           = numVal
    , EndHour             = numVal
from tbl_agentTime a
    join numberz n on n.numVal >= a.BeginHour and n.numVal<= a.EndHour
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a Recursive CTE it would look something like this...

```
WITH    cte
          AS (SELECT    [AgentName],
                        [AgentState],
                        [BeginTransitionTime],
                        [EndTransitionTime],
                        [NewEndTransitionTime] = DATEADD(second,-1,DATEADD(hour,DATEDIFF(hour,0,[BeginTransitionTime]) + 1,0)),
                        [BeginHour],
                        [EndHour] = [BeginHour]
              FROM      agents
              UNION ALL
              SELECT    [AgentName],
                        [AgentState],
                        DATEADD(hour,DATEDIFF(hour,0,[NewEndTransitionTime]) + 1,0),
                        [EndTransitionTime],
                        [NewEndTransitionTime] = CASE WHEN [EndTransitionTime] < [NewEndTransitionTime] THEN [EndTransitionTime]
                                                      ELSE DATEADD(second,-1,DATEADD(hour,DATEDIFF(hour,0,[NewEndTransitionTime]) + 2,0))
                                                 END,
                        [BeginHour] + 1,
                        [EndHour] + 1
              FROM      cte
              WHERE     DATEADD(hour,DATEDIFF(hour,0,[NewEndTransitionTime]) + 1,0) < [EndTransitionTime]
             )
    SELECT  [AgentName],
            [AgentState],
            [BeginTransitionTime],
            [EndTransitionTime] = CASE WHEN [EndTransitionTime] < [NewEndTransitionTime] THEN [EndTransitionTime] ELSE [NewEndTransitionTime] END,
            [BeginHour],
            [EndHour]
    FROM    cte
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5d387/1)

This can also be done using a number table.. Although this is slower with only a few records, it might be faster with larger data sets.

```
WITH    E1(N)
          AS (SELECT    1
              UNION ALL
              SELECT    1
              UNION ALL
              SELECT    1
              UNION ALL
              SELECT    1
              UNION ALL
              SELECT    1
             ),                          
        E2([Hour])
          AS (SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL
                                                    )) Num
              FROM      E1 a,
                        E1 b
             )
    SELECT  [AgentName],
            [AgentState],
            [BeginTransitionTime] = CASE WHEN a.BeginHour = E2.[Hour] 
                                        THEN [BeginTransitionTime] 
                                        ELSE DATEADD(hour,DATEDIFF(hour,0,[BeginTransitionTime]) + (E2.[Hour] - a.BeginHour),0) 
                                    END,
            [EndTransitionTime] =   CASE WHEN [EndTransitionTime] < DATEADD(second, -1 , DATEADD(hour,DATEDIFF(hour,0,[BeginTransitionTime]) + (E2.[Hour] - a.BeginHour + 1),0))
                                        THEN [EndTransitionTime] 
                                        ELSE DATEADD(second, -1 , DATEADD(hour,DATEDIFF(hour,0,[BeginTransitionTime]) + (E2.[Hour] - a.BeginHour + 1),0))
                                    END,
            [BeginHour] = E2.[Hour],
            [EndHour] = E2.[Hour]
    FROM    agents a
            JOIN E2 ON E2.[Hour] BETWEEN a.BeginHour AND a.EndHour
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5d387/2)

Comment: The point of the numbers table isn't to (re)create in the CTE, it's to have it in an operations database and use it instead of a CTE.  And it is much faster at scale.  If you don't have a numbers table or don't want to use one, then your first example would be what I went with.

Comment: @SteveMangiameli  i tried all 3 approaches, and the permanent numbers table was the slowest on a small scale.. but i haven't tested it using more than a few records.. http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNE30.png

Comment: this is not scientific, but this is based on 1000 rows in agent table..   http://i.stack.imgur.com/hKDOV.png